# Why are these divs all aligned differently?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

We're using a flexbox-based front-end framework ([Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/system/flexbox/#main-content)), and I'm strangely finding that all of these components (specifically, the quantity control bits) are being laid out differently, even though they're all using the same styling and code.

Take a look:
[image: Material UI aligns each component uniquely]

I'm almost certain this is a flexbox issue, not a Material UI issue. Do you have any idea what's going on here? Note: all the styling is done inline.

#### Code Sample

Note: this is the code for each one of these `<Card>`s, which each consumes a `listing` as a prop that contains the data it needs to render.

```
<Card style={{ display: "flex", height: "13em" }}>
  <CardMedia title={listing.productTitle}>
    <img src={listing.mainImgUrl} style={{ width: "13em" }} />
  </CardMedia>
  <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">
    <CardContent style={{ flex: "1 0 auto" }}>
      <Typography component="h6">{listing.productTitle}</Typography>
      <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="textSecondary">
        by {listing.creatorUsername.length > 16 ? `${listing.creatorUsername.substring(0, 13)}...` : listing.creatorUsername}
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>
    <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="flex-end" mb={1}>
      <Box display='flex' alignItems='center'>
        <Box mr={2}>
          <Typography variant='body2'>${localQuantity * listing.price}</Typography>
        </Box>
      <Select
        name="quantity"
        value={localQuantity}
        onChange={handleChange}
        variant="outlined"
        disabled={disabled.quantity}
      >
        {getQuantityOptions(listing.numAvailable)}
        </Select>
      <IconButton>
        <DeleteOutline />
      </IconButton>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  </Box>
</Card>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem seems to be that `CardContent` set its size to fit the content. I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Put the quantity component in the bottom right corner or set it in the bottom center.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, @Titus. I'm trying to right-align the quantity component.

Comment: It looks like the conponent `CardContent` is missing `flex-grow: 1`(for some reason) can you try to remove `style={{ flex: "1 0 auto" }}` and replace it with `flexGrow={1}`

Comment: Dang, that didn't work @CedricCholley. It didn't change anything. Thanks for taking a look though.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Box after the card content to 100% width then you can use margin-left:auto on the first element inside to align it right. Its a little hard to guess when i can't run the code :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching the `<CardContent>` tag, because it was doing something funky to the layout. Here's the solution I ended up with (basically using `<Box>`es (basically a straight `<div>`):

```
       <Card style={{ display: "flex", height: "13em" }}>
        <CardMedia title={listing.productTitle}>
          <img src={listing.mainImgUrl} style={{ width: "13em" }} />
        </CardMedia>
        <Container>
          <Box mt={2}>
            <Box display="flex" alignContent="flex-start">
              <Box display="block">
                <Typography component="h6">{listing.productTitle}</Typography>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="textSecondary">
                  by{" "}
                  {listing.creatorUsername.length > 16
                    ? `${listing.creatorUsername.substring(0, 13)}...`
                    : listing.creatorUsername}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary">
                  ${listing.price} each
                </Typography>
              </Box>
            </Box>
            <Box
              display="flex"
              alignContent="flex-end"
              justifyContent="flex-end"
              my={1}
            >
              <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
                <Box mr={2}>
                  <Typography variant="body2">
                    ${listing.quantity * listing.price}
                  </Typography>
                </Box>
                <Select
                  name="quantity"
                  value={listing.quantity}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  variant="outlined"
                  disabled={disabled.quantity}
                >
                  {getQuantityOptions(listing.numAvailable)}
                </Select>
                <IconButton onClick={handleDelete}>
                  <DeleteOutline />
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Container>
      </Card>
```